# can i do loadtest for html website in jmeter

Tags: load-testing

I have written a code in html for signup a website and saved into my local machine with .html extension.
In browser it showing as file:///C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/hello.html
can I able to do loadtest for this url using jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

**No** (unless you are testing the speed of your [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)).

The whole idea of load testing is:

1. Have your web site deployed onto environment close to real (the one, you'r going to have in production) so you need to consider some form of a [web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) software (and hardware) and deploy your website there
2. Mimic the load coming from real users as close as possible. It means that your JMeter test should look like [exactly a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) from the web server's perspective.

This way you should be able to confirm whether your web site is capable of handling anticipated load (or determine its boundaries so see where/when it fails)

More information:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [Logging in to a web-site](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#logging_in)

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter measure the speed between to requests, and generally the backend speed. If you want to test your file on directly on your disk without any http ou application server , Jmeter is not the good tool. The loading time page speed can be measured  by the Browser Developer tools (F12 key browser) .